# Javascript - using form input value within a modal

Tags: javascript, forms, modal-dialog

I keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

or: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')

When trying to change the text of an anchor tag after a modal opens.

Here's the modal:

```
 <!-- Success Modal -->
    <div class="modal-container" id="modal">
        <div class="modal-main">
            <img
                src="./assets/images/icon-success.svg"
                alt="success image"
            />
            <h1 class="modal-header">Thanks for subscribing!</h1>
            <p>
                A confirmation email has been sent to
                <a href="#" id="modal-email">test</a>. Please open it and
                click the button inside to confirm your subscription.
               
            </p>
        </div>
        <button id="dismiss-btn">Dismiss message</button>
    </div>
```

The Form:

```
   <form id="form">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                placeholder="email@company.com"
            />
            <button id="button">Subscribe to monthly newsletter</button>
        </form>
```

and the Javascript:

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const btn = document.getElementById("button");
const dismissBtn = document.getElementById("dismiss-btn");
const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
const modelEmail = document.getElementById("model-email");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.style.display = "block";

    let formData = new FormData(this);
    let inputValue = formData.get("email");

    console.log(inputValue);
    modelEmail.textContent = "example";
});

dismissBtn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
};
```

The correct value appears in the console when console logging the inputValue, but I keep getting errors when trying to change the textContent of the anchor tag in the modal. Whether I use the inputValue or [in this case] the string of "example", I keep getting the null error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the `modelEmail` doesn't reference the element. So the property `textContent` does not exist. From what I can see there are 2 cases:

1. You query the your `modelEmail` with this: `document.getElementById("model-email")` which seems like you did a typo because in your html the closest id to this is "modal-email".
2. If the typo was just in the post and not in your code then you most likely try to access the modal before rendering it. For example this happens if you try to access the modal initially with js but you don't render the modal until submition. In this case you have to move the dom query inside the event, somewhere that will be a guarantee that the query will run after the modal has been rendered.

Comment: God damnit, yeah you're right it was a typo.